# Two signing tabs, only one is required

Tags: docusignapi

I have a form with two signing tabs. This is a privacy consent form with a checkbox so that if the user wants to opt out, they click the checkbox and sign the second tab. If they are okay with the form, they don't check the checkbox and they sign the first tab. But a signature is required one way or another. Conditional fields sound like the answer, but it seems like they are mainly used for hide/show of fields. I'm trying to do this thru a template, not thru the api.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. I needed to make the signing tabs not mandatory. Then, I set up the rule on the checkbox to show\hide depending on the checkbox state. The key was making the signing tabs not mandatory.